# I use numpy to find inverse of A matrix but numpy answer is not true why?

Tags: python, numpy

I use numpy to find inverse of A matrix
but numpy answer is not true why?
my code is:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((4, 4))
A[0, :] = [10, 2, 3, 4]
A[1, :] = [5, 6, 7, 8]
A[2, :] = [9, 10, 11, 12]
A[3, :] = [13, 14, 15, 16]
print(A)
B = np.linalg.inv(A)
print(B)
print(np.dot(A, B)) # is not equal I
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `A`'s rank is less than 4, which means its determinant is 0 (if you look at the formula for [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) you would easily see why this is true):

```
assert np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) < len(A)
assert np.allclose(np.linalg.det(A), 0)
```

A square matrix is invertible only if it's nonsingular, i.e. if its determinant is nonzero. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Comment: Thank you. but how numpy comupte a inverse for A?

Comment: @Rami LU decomposition, so Gaussian elimination really.

Comment: See https://www.py4u.net/discuss/153049 for a discussion of this.  Essentially numpy does LU decomposition, but doesn't bother checking to see if its result really makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. I understand numpy method for Matrix inverse computation.